# Не получается залить градиентом круг так же, как в Photoshop

Tags: svg, icon, photoshop

Пытаюсь сделать круг с градиентной заливкой как получилось в Фотошопе. Но в SVG градиент получается не таким плавным, как в PS + не совпадают цвета. Что я делаю не так?

[image: SVG] PS, макет: https://yadi.sk/i/3i0SyKRZ3JNATL

SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30">
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#bb2493"/>
    <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#ffb100"/>
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ed0700"/>
    <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#05b1fc"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#bb2493"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <circle fill="transparent" stroke-width="2.51" r="12.49" cx="15" cy="15" stroke="url(#linear-gradient)"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый и последний цвет - лишние, + направлены в другую сторону:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30">
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#05b1fc"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ed0700"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffb100"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <circle fill="transparent" stroke-width="2.51" r="12.49" cx="15" cy="15" stroke="url(#linear-gradient)"></circle>
</svg>
```

Это легко увидеть, если открыть ваш код в inkscape:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]